# Understanding Prime Test

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, primes

I have this Haskell script:

```
prime :: Integer -> Bool    
prime 1 = False
prime n = [ x | x <- [2..n-1], n `mod` x == 0 ] == []
```

What does the first `x` in the last line stand for? Why can I replace it with "String" and the whole function still works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part before `|` in a list comprehension is an expression which will be used to generate each element of the resulting list.

In this case, the function only cares about whether the list comprehension results in an empty list or not, so the elements of the list don't matter. You could put `()`, `x`, `1` or any value of any type which implements `Eq` there. If you had used `null` instead of `== []` to check for emptiness, it could have been anything, even `undefined`.

Comment: "If you had used `null` instead of `== []` to check for emptiness, it could have been anything, even `undefined`." In any case, it could be anything, even `undefined`.

Comment: @newacct: No, the `Eq` instance for lists requires an `Eq` instance for the elements, even if we never actually call it. So it couldn't be `undefined :: a -> a`, for example.

Comment: @newacct: okay, so you're right that `null` works better than `== []` because `== []` doesn't work on things that are not `Eq`. However, `undefined` by itself works, so that part of your answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: @newacct: It's an ambiguous type error, unless have GHCi's `ExtendedDefaultRules`.